# C# DateTime.ToString return different result in Ubuntu and Centos

Tags: c#, datetime, ubuntu, centos, invariantculture

I have the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var dateTime = DateTimeHelper
        .ConvertPersianDateTime("12/22/1402", "09:33:12")
        .ToString("D");

     Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}
```

```
public static DateTime ConvertPersianDateTime(string persianDate, string persianTime)
{
    var isParse = DateTime.TryParse($"{persianDate} {persianTime}",
                                new CultureInfo("fa-IR"),
                                DateTimeStyles.None, out var result);

    return isParse ? result : DateTime.Now;
}
```

When I run the program in ubuntu server, I get this result:

```
Tuesday, March 12, 2024
```

But when I run the program in centos server, I get this result:

```
Wednesday, December 22, 1402
```

Why result of centos server is different with ubuntu?

Comment: Is month/day/year order even valid for that locale? I thought month/day/year order was specific to the United States and a few areas nearby that are influenced by it. Almost everyone else in the world uses day/month/year or year/month/day.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, I run this code right now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This code work successfully in Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: I never said it didn't run. But wow, I've just tried it on DotNetFiddle and also got March 12th 2024, which I find really surprising. I updated it to make it clear whether it parsed or not, and it says it did. But again, please see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78171897/datetime-tostring-return-different-result-in-ubuntu-and-centos#comment137813966_78171897) about the order. (Though I tried day/month/year and it didn't even parse.) In any case, good luck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related with this [Github issue.](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/82681)

> I quickly looked at Centos OS and I found the [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) there **not setting**
> the `PersianCalendar` as the default calendar to the `fa-IR`. So by
> default it uses the `GregorianCalendar` as the default calendar there.
> You can work around this easily by manually setting the
> `PersianCalendar` as the default calendar in the created culture object.

Also from this [supported distributions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos#supported-distributions) page;

> The following table is a list of currently supported .NET releases on
> CentOS Linux 7. These versions remain supported until either the
> version of .NET reaches end-of-support or the version of CentOS Linux
> is no longer supported.
>
> CentOS Linux 7 --> .NET 7, 6
>
> **CentOS Linux 8 reached an early End Of Life (EOL) on December 31st**,
> 2021. For more information, see the official [CentOS Linux EOL page](https://www.centos.org/centos-linux-eol/). Because of this, .NET isn't supported on CentOS Linux 8.

So, this looks like a ICU problem rather than a .NET problem. You can always [file an issue](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/ICU/issues) for that but remember Centos 8 is not supporting OS any more for .NET development.

---

**Update:**

By adding `PersianCalendar` to `CultureInfo` problem will fix:

```
public static DateTime ConvertPersianDateTime(string persianDate, string persianTime)
{
    var faCulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");

    faCulture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new PersianCalendar(); // This what will make it work.

    var isParse = DateTime.TryParse($"{persianDate} {persianTime}",
                                faCulture,
                                DateTimeStyles.None, out var result);

    return isParse ? result : DateTime.Now;
}
```